# Release graphics when app entered to background mode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

In Apple documentation you can find that Apple recommends to release heavy data like images when your app is entering to background mode.
How to release images from `UIViews` and an other data?
How to release images from `UIViews` from all `viewController` right way?
How to restore data when app get `applicationWillResignActive` message?

If somebody have a good example or link, please show it.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? OK, it is a vague question but actually a good one. It would be actually nice to see a good answer to this (i.e. useful for beginners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to app delegate 2 methods

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_APP_BACKGROUND object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_APP_BACKGROUND object:nil];
}
```

Make BaseViewController with methods:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillForeground) name:NOTIFICATION_APP_FOREGROUND object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBackground) name:NOTIFICATION_APP_BACKGROUND object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)appDidBackground {
}

- (void)appWillForeground {

}
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Subclass all your view controllers from BaseViewController. In method appDidBackground you should release unneeded data, in appWillForeground - restore it

Comment: 1. Some one told to me that if use `[UIImage imagenamed:@"image.png"]` - this will not release image from memory. 2. How to save you data and restore then. Use NSUserDefaults? If you use coreData it's easy. But how to save nsarray for example, I can save it to nsuserdefaults or to plist file. What is the right way?

Comment: 1. [UIImage imageNamed] caches all images. it will may be released on memory warning.
2. For save a lot data you should user coredata, for a few data - NSUserDefaults is good way. If you want to save a array (in NSUserDefaults) with some custom objects you should realize NSCoding protocol for each custom class in it.

Comment: How to release UIView that were added with loadView. Some people says that need to use viewDidUnload, but app enter to background mode this method doesn't invoke.